# In iPhone App How to change fontstyle throughout the App?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

In iPhone App I want to change the fontstyle throughout ( in whole App) the App
so is there any quicker way of doing that. suppose I want display all font in style "impact" ,

How can I set fontstyle "impact" throughout the app ?

Please Help and Suggest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The SDK does not allow you to change font settings on an application-wide basis.  If you want to change the default font, you have to do it on a per-object basis.

Also, are you sure that this is a good idea?  Changing the default font to "Impact" might not have the "impact" you're looking for...

Comment: Thanks for reply, impact i have given as an example only You can consider "times" or something else thanks for reply once again so is there any way instead of changing for object to object.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use a Settings.bundle so the user can choose what font they would like to see throughout the app. This is done on a per object basis as Dave suggests.

### Per Object:

```
[myLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"kFontStyle"] 
                                 size:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"kFontSize"]]];
```

### In a UIWebView:

This is an example of how I use them when loading HTML into a `UIWebView`

```
header = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><style>body{background-color:transparent;font-family:%@;font-size:%@px;color:#960000;}</style></head><body><div align='left'><center><img width='290' height='56' src='0%i.jpg'></center><br>",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"kFontStyle"],[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] int stringForKey:@"kFontSize"],courseIndex] retain];
footer = @"</font></font></font></div></body></html>";
[myWebView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",header,[courseItem objectForKey:@"Content"],footer] baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:bundle]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could subclass UIFont and override methods like systemFontWithSize: to return your custom font. You could even do this in a category for UIFont. I do agree with Dave though, be careful with custom fonts.